# How to maintain login session in html5

Tags: javascript, html, session

I am a beginner to html5.

I am developing a webapp which demands me to maintain user login session.

Is that possible to maintain session using HTML5 and javascript only ?

If it is , an example demo or link will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try sessionStorage. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe using cookies could provide the desired result:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

An example of saving cookies is

```
document.cookie="session=john doe";
```

Then, to read the cookie:

```
var session = document.cookie;
```

If you are looking for something that lasts longer, take a look at DOM storage, however, I can't help you with that because it is beyond my scope of knowledge. Either way, the link is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: just concerned about using sessionStorage , do it will give me same security and flexibility like asp or jsp gives ? can i code it to have one user session at a time ?

Comment: @user3531182 Absolutely, it works per-user and is VERY secure! There is absolutely no need to worry about security with this function.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you are looking for `sessionStorage`.

A simple example from [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

```
// Save data to the current session's store
sessionStorage.setItem("username", "John");
// Access some stored data
alert( "username = " + sessionStorage.getItem("username"));
```

Comment: just concerned about using sessionStorage , do it will give me same  security and flexibility like asp or jsp gives ? can i code it to have one user session at a time ?

Comment: what if the browser is not closed, how will you timeout the session in this case